# Trouble with PostgreSQL pgRouting function pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I am trying to use the `pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix` function in pgRouting for PostgreSQL to find the shortest paths between points in a road network. However, I keep encountering an error indicating that the function is not found. Here is a simplified version of my query:

```sql
WITH incident_location AS (
    SELECT fire_id, wkb_geometry AS fire_location
    FROM fire_incident
    WHERE fire_id = 'Fire_00001'
)
SELECT
    incident_location.fire_id,
    fire_stations.station_id,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(incident_location.fire_location)::json->'coordinates' AS incident_coordinates,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(fire_stations.wkb_geometry)::json->'coordinates' AS station_coordinates,
    pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
        'SELECT road_edge_id as id, road_source as source, road_target as target, road_length as cost FROM road_network',
        incident_location.fire_location::geometry(Point, 4326),
        ARRAY(SELECT wkb_geometry::geometry(Point, 4326) FROM fire_stations),
        false
    ) AS cost
FROM
    incident_location
JOIN
    fire_stations ON incident_location.fire_id = fire_stations.station_id
ORDER BY cost[1] ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
ERROR: function pgr_dijkstracostmatrix(unknown, geometry, geometry[], boolean) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Character: 439
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/en/pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix.html) `pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix` function has only three parameters, but you are giving it four.

In such a case PostgreSQL will complain that such function does not exist.